# How to send xml via post to wcf service

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I got a code which post xml to wcf service. Here is the full code

1) WCF Service Interface

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "GetData",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
string GetData(DataRequest parameter);
```

2) WCF Service Implementation

```
public string GetData(DataRequest parameter)
{
    //Do stuff
    return "your data here";
}
```

3) Data Contract in your WCF service (In this case it's DataRequest)

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "YourNamespaceHere")]
public class DataRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID{ get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Data{ get; set; }
}
```

4) Client sending the data must have the data constructed properly! (C# console app in this case)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    string SampleXml = "<DataRequest xmlns=\"YourNamespaceHere\">" +
                                    "<ID>" +
                                    yourIDVariable +
                                    "</ID>" +
                                    "<Data>" +
                                    yourDataVariable +
                                    "</Data>" +
                                "</DataRequest>";

    string postData = SampleXml.ToString();
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    string url = "http://localhost:62810/MyService.svc/GetData";

    string strResult = string.Empty;

    // declare httpwebrequet wrt url defined above
    HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    // set method as post
    webrequest.Method = "POST";
    // set content type
    webrequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
    // set content length
    webrequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
    // get stream data out of webrequest object
    Stream newStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    newStream.Close();

    //Gets the response
    WebResponse response = webrequest.GetResponse();
    //Writes the Response
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();

    return s;
}
```

My question is that if GetData() function expect two or more parameter then how could I supply value to GetData()

```
public string GetData(string xml1,string xml2)
{
     //Do stuff return "your data here";
}
```

so please guide me how to pass two xml data to `GetData()` function ?

Comment: Just to understand: why don't you just create a Service Reference? Would make the scenario lots easier and also safer as the caller would use strongly typed classes instead of variable XML data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't have a service with `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` and a method that takes two parameters. You'll need to change to a `WrappedRequest` as a minimum:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
     UriTemplate = "GetData",
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
string GetData(DataRequest xml1, string xml2);
```

With that out of the way let's see what the wire format needs to be for this `webHttp` binding.

The root element needs to be named as the name of the operation, `GetData`. Next are a sequence of child elements, for each parameter one. The default name of those elements equals the name of your variable, so in the example it would be `xml1` and `xml2`. Those defaults can be influenced by decorating the parameter with a `[MessageParameter(Name="Bar")]` attribute.

Applying above ground rules would require that your HTTP Post body looks similar to this:

```
<GetData>    <!-- Operation -->
    <xml1>   <!-- parameter one -->
    </xml1>
    <xml2>   <!-- parameter two -->
    </xml2>
</GetData>
```

Unfortunately this is not it. The service and it's contracts have namespace. Without any decoration the namespace is the ugly `http://tempuri.org/` which I replaced on the `IService` interface with

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace="http://service.stackoverflow.com")]
```

In your first example the `DataRequest` type had a namespace. In my test I decorated the type with

```
 [DataContract(Namespace="http://data.stackoverflow.com")]
```

Now we need to add those namespaces (with namespace aliases) to our basic xml payload:

```
<GetData xmlns="http://service.stackoverflow.com"> <!-- Operation with default namespace  -->
    <xml1 xmlns:a="http://data.stackoverflow.com">   <!-- namespace on type -->
      <a:ID>42</a:ID> <!-- members are in the type namespace, use the alias --> 
      <a:Data>FuBar</a:Data> 
    </xml1>
    <xml2>   <!-- parameter two, no explicit namespace so is in the default one -->
       BlahBlah
    </xml2>
</GetData>
```

Posting that payload to the service at `Service1.svc/GetData` does invoke the service with the parameters having the deserialized data.

To answer your question exactly given your example code change at the Service:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://service.stackoverflow.com")]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
      UriTemplate = "GetData",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    string GetData([MessageParameter(Name="Bar")] DataRequest xml1, string xml2);
}
```

and at the client:

```
var yourIDVariable = "foo";
var yourDataVariable = "bar";
string SampleXml = "<xml1 xmlns:a=\"http://data.stackoverflow.com\">" +
                                "<a:ID>" +
                                yourIDVariable +
                                "</a:ID>" +
                                "<a:Data>" +
                                yourDataVariable +
                                "</a:Data>" +
                            "</xml1>";

string xml2 = "some data";
string wrapper = "<GetData xmlns=\"http://service.stackoverflow.com\">{0}<xml2>{1}</xml2></GetData>";
string postData = String.Format(wrapper, SampleXml, xml2);
```

When dealing with WCF service call and diagnosing serialization issues it is extremely convenient to enable WCF message logging in the config of `system.serviceModel`:

```
<diagnostics>
  <endToEndTracing activityTracing="true" messageFlowTracing="true" propagateActivity="true"/>
  <messageLogging
     logKnownPii="true"
     logEntireMessage="true" 
     logMalformedMessages="true"
     logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
     logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
     maxMessagesToLog="30000"
     maxSizeOfMessageToLog="20000"/>
</diagnostics>
```

and the suitable listener:

```
<system.diagnostics>
   <sources>
     <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
       <listeners>
             <add name="messages"
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="messages.svclog" />
        </listeners>
     </source>
  </sources>
  <trace autoflush="true"></trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Which gives you the exact payload in the [Service Trace Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQlF7.png):